# Liferay shows white page after login to cas

Tags: nginx, ssl, liferay, cas

I have installed cas-overlay-template-master with a tomcat 9.0.41 listening on 8080 proxied by an nginx listening on 443 in a domain called `cas.mydomain.net` with an ssl created with letsencrypt which is currently valid.
In the below directory

```
/opt/cas/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/cas/
```

and a host in the `/opt/cas/apache-tomcat-9.0.41/conf/server.xml`

```
<Host name="cas.mydomain.net"  appBase="cas" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="cas.mydomain.net_access_log" suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

I have created a file called `/etc/cas/config/services/myliferay-1001.json` with the bellow content

```
{
  @class: org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService
  serviceId: https://myliferay.mydomain.net/c/portal/login.*
  name: myliferay
  id: 1001
  proxyTicketExpirationPolicy:
  {
    @class: org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceProxyTicketExpirationPolicy
  }
  serviceTicketExpirationPolicy:
  {
    @class: org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceServiceTicketExpirationPolicy
  }
  evaluationOrder: 1
  logoutType: FRONT_CHANNEL
  attributeReleasePolicy:
  {
    @class: org.apereo.cas.services.DenyAllAttributeReleasePolicy
  }
  logoutUrl: https://cas.mydomain.net/logout
}
```

I also connected cas into a postgres db placing the following into `/etc/cas/config/cas.properties`

```
cas.server.name=https://cas.mydomain.net
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}
logging.config=file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
Log4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector

cas.authn.accept.users=
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].driver-class=org.postgresql.Driver
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cas
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].driver-class=org.postgresql.Driver
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].user=postgres
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password=
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].sql=SELECT * FROM users WHERE emailaddress = ?
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password-encoder.type=DEFAULT
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].password-encoder.encoding-algorithm=MD5
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].field-password=password
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].field-expired=expired
cas.authn.jdbc.query[0].field-disabled=disabled
```

I created a table users and a user with a certain email and password and I can login from the web... all work!

I have also installed liferay-dxp 7.3 which comes with tomcat 9.0.37 listening on 8081 proxied by an nginx listening on 443 under the domain `myliferay.mydomain.net` with also with an ssl created with letsencrypt which is currently valid.
In the below directory

```
/opt/liferay/
```

and a host in the `/opt/liferay/tomcat-9.0.37/conf/server.xml`

```
<Host name="myliferay.mydomain.net"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
        prefix="myliferay.mydomain.net_access_log" suffix=".txt"
        pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
</Host>
```

Installing liferay I chose a postgres db on localhost/iportal which was predefined.
A user in liferay was created which I chose to have the same email and password as the one I use in the cas db

In liferay `control panel -> system settings -> sso -> cas` I made the following settings

```
Enable - Checked
Import from LDPA: Unchecked

Login URL: https://cas.mydomain.net

Logout on Session Expiration: Unchecked

Logout URL: https://cas.mydomain.net/logout
Server Name: https://myliferay.mydomain.net
Server URL: https://cas.mydomain.net
Service URL: https://myliferay.mydomain.net/c/portal/login
No Such User Redirect URL: https://myliferay.mydomain.net
```

Now I browsed to `https://myliferay.mydomain.net` and clicked on `Sign In` on the upper right corner which redirected me to

```
https://cas.mydomain.net/login?service=https%3A%2F%2Fmyliferay.mydomain.net%2Fc%2Fportal%2Flogin
```

and presented me with the Cas login screen.

When I use a random email or password cas represents me with the login screen as expected.

If I use the correct email and password it redirects me to

```
https://myliferay.mydomain.net/c/portal/login?ticket=ST-21-[arandomstring]-[myserverhostname]
```

which is a blank page, and also if I browse to `https://myliferay.mydomain.net` I am still logged out.
If I click Sign In again I am redirected instantly to cas.mydomain.net and back to

```
https://myliferay.mydomain.net/c/portal/login?ticket=ST-22-[arandomstring]-[myserverhostname]
```

Which means that cas already knows who I am but
Its like liferay does not know how to handle the `ticket parameter` in the request

Am I supposed to create any other file somewhere?
Am I supposed to somehow install cas.mydomain.net or/and myliferay.mydomain.net ssl certificate to each tomcat installation?
Am I supposed to make any other setting into liferay's control panel?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by placing the following two lines in `webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties`

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.BasicAutoLogin
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.BasicAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin
```

and in `com.liferay.filters.ss.cas.CASFilter` the following line

```
com.liferay.filters.sso.cas.CASFilter=true
```